# config.cache_clearAtMidnight = 1 in condition

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

For some pages with the event list plugin from EXT:cal the cache should be deleted every midnight. I did this typoscript code in template file:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id=4010, TSFE:id=3749, TSFE:id=5217, TSFE:id=4123]
    config.cache_clearAtMidnight = 1
[GLOBAL]
```

Unfortunely this does not work in TYPO3 CMS 7.6.19. How can I delete cache at midnight for some pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my page `config.cache_period = 604800` is set. In this case the condition content has to be expanded:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 4010|3749|5217|4123|1861|1495|221|1372|3142|3994|4390]
    config.cache_period = 86400
    config.cache_clearAtMidnight = 1
[GLOBAL]
```

I report this as a core bug: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82380

Answer (score 2):

"Clear at midnight" means that upon writing the page cache entry, the timeout is set to seconds-until-midnight (`typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php get_cache_timeout()`).

Maybe you just have to clear the frontend cache.

---

Btw, the TypoScript condition is ok but could be made much shorter.
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#id45

Comment: Thank you for the hint to the core function. I found a bug in core and report them to TYPO3: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82380

Answer (score 1):

Adapt your TS condition according to TS reference https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#id45

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id = 4010|3749|5217|4123]
    config.cache_clearAtMidnight = 1
[GLOBAL]
```

This will match, if the page-id is equal to either 4010, 3749, 5217 or 4123.

Comment: But the condition is ok as it is.